# как записывать всё, что делает пользователь в телеграм боте (pytelegrambotapi)

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

пишу бота в телеграм используя библиотеку pytelegrambotapi и столкнулся с такой проблемой:

В определённый момент мне нужно, чтобы бот записывал всё, что пользователь присылает (это может быть как текст, так и файлы) в текстовый файл в формате username_id_<текст или название файла>
бот умеет скачивать всё, что ему присылается в папку поэтому название файла можно брать из этой функции

но как получать все сообщения от пользователя и потом записывать их в текстовый файл я так и не разобрался

Comment: Можно создать чат(только для себя) куда ты будет переотправлять все сообщения от пользователя. типа message_forward. + ты можешь вытаскивать user name, id и тд

Comment: в этом и проблема, что в чат пересылать не очень удобно будет, чтобы потом читать эту инфу, да и плюс там будет большое количество пользователей

Comment: если говорить только о тексте, то конечно можно записывать в файл + user_name + user_id, например. 
но если нам нужно хранить видео, фото, документы... то тут проще просто все скачивать под чистую на пк или сервер - известный факт, что данные о сообщение хранятся не так долго. Но будет ли это удобнее отдельного чата? Не думаю.

Comment: мне как раз нужно просто текст сохранять. если будут фото или видео, то он их отдельно скачивает в папку. а мне бы просто то, что пользователь будет вводить боту

Answer (score 1):

```
import telebot
from datetime import datetime

bot = telebot.TeleBot('1:A')

print(bot.get_me())


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def log(message):
    a_log = open(f'log_{message.chat.id}.txt', 'a')
    a_log.write(f'{datetime.now()}: {message.text}\n')


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

будет записывать в файл `log_%chat_id%.txt` весь текст который пользователь присылает боту в формате

> 2022-02-28 15:14:40.097234: /start

> 2022-02-28 15:15:29.118561: hi

> 2022-02-28 15:15:32.172062: test

*при необходимости можно повесить на другой обработчик (handler).*

P.S. **не забудьте закрыть файл** (`a_log.close()`)